# How to disable automatic conversion of varchar to text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a view which unions two identical tables (only difference is the table name):

```
mysql> describe tbl_a;
...
| value | varchar(3072) | ...

(same for tbl_b)
```

The view is created by using

```
create view vw_union_ab as select * from tbl_a union all select * from tbl_b;
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
mysql> describe vw_union_ab;
...
| value | text | ...
```

The column type of `value` has changed from `varchar(3072)` to `text`, and this is not what I want; I want to preserve the original data type which is `varchar(3072)`.

Is there a way for me to preserve the data type?

Comment: 1) No way - the datatype may be saved only for a field which is not processed. 2) The `VARCHAR` makes sense only while storing on disk. 3) Pay attention - there not exists `CAST` to `VARCHAR` at all. 4) *I want to preserve the original data type* Why? For what reason?

Comment: @Akina The reason is because this behavior shows up only in the latest version I have which is 8.0.18 (production does not have 8.0.19 yet); up to now no such conversion has ever happened.

Comment: I think this is dependent by the inner data format used for UNIONed field in the final recordset. Of course, this could change in the new version.

Comment: @Akina - I have seen the same issue too. Regarding 4) ; since the value is returned as text, Hibernate (version 3) layer fires an error since it can't handle LONGVARCHAR. The error is "org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1". In my application this error occurs intermittently. No sure whether this happens due to any other complexities like character sets.